# Strategy for this auction on 100 coin flips question?

Tags: probability, game-theory, expected-value, nash-equilibrium, auction-theory

Got an interesting interview/game question today:

> You have the opportunity to participate in an auction for a treasure chest. The seller anonymously flips 200 coins, and for each head he adds \$1 to the treasure chest, and nobody else knows how much is in this chest. Everyone bids a price simultaneously, and the person with the highest bid wins. (If more than one person chooses the same highest number, the winner is chosen randomly.) What should your optimal strategy be?

Now, I’ve seen a few auction questions on this site, but they still boggle me as to how an optimal strategy would work. I only know that:

1. The expected value of the chest is \$100.
2. This auction is symmetric, and everyone should have the same strategy for Nash equilibrium.
3. The probability of having the winning bid is $\frac1{n}$ where $n$ is the number of people. (I imagine it as arranging $n$ numbers on a line and the probability of being assigned the first one.)

How should one piece these together? Should I be aiming to maximise profit or minimise losses? Would bidding \$50 be better than \$100, and should I even bid at all? Edit: the comments say bidding \$99 is the best bid, why is this so? Is this the case for any number of people?

Mathematically speaking is it correct to say would if I bid \$$b$, my expected value is $(100-b)/n$? Still it feels odd that the strategy is just bidding \$100 — not sure if this is too risky...

All help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I am not sure about your statement (3) not seeming to take account of the amount bid.  That being said, I might bid $99$ and might expect everybody else to do the same.

Comment: This seems to require an assumption on how the other bidders "value" that chest. In the case everyone is assumed to be smart player with a set strategy, then what is the tiebreaker in the auction? It seems that everyone would want to bid the exact same amount. Could you assume the bets follow a particular probabilistic model centered around $99 (which seems to be the best long term positive expected value bid)?

Comment: @Henry Hi what do you mean by that? Also, how is \$99 a better bid?

Comment: @DinosaurEgg Hi, why is \$99 the best long term bid? Should I model a skewed PMF, and how to I assign probabilities to the other bids?

Comment: $\$100$ gives an expected return of $0$, so any lower bid cannot do worse than this and may do better

Comment: @Henry is this for any number of auction participants?

Comment: If a $\$100$ loses then the return is $0$; if a $\$100$ bid wins then the chest holds an expected $\$100$ so the expected return is $0$.  This holds for any number of auction participants

Comment: @Henry So what would make a \$99 bid be more preferable to a \$50 one?

Comment: @user107224: A bid of $\$99$ beats any lower bid, and has a positive expectation (assuming no one foolishly bids higher).